# TextView alignment for programmatically added TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout

I am adding text views programmatically, and for some reason they are loading up all *on top* f one another instead of one after another.

Although the problem is rather suited to a LinearLayout, I'd like to do this in a RelativeLayout.

Here is the relevant xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity.DetailFragment"
    android:id="@+id/detail_top_layout">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/detail_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and (hopefully) the relevant Fragment code:

```
    private TextView __textViewFactory(String s, RelativeLayout r, Context c, TextView above){
        TextView tv = new TextView(c);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.abc_primary_text_material_light));
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, above.getId());

        tv.setText(s);
        r.addView(tv, p);

        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "started");
        RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.detail_top_layout);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        try {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            TextView tv = __textViewFactory(Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(COL_WEATHER_ID)), rootView, context, (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_text));
            tv = __textViewFactory(Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(COL_WEATHER_DATE)), rootView, context, tv);
            tv = __textViewFactory(cursor.getString(COL_WEATHER_DESC), rootView, context, tv);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text))
              .setText(mForecastStr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
        RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.detail_top_layout);

        if (rootView != null) {
            int c = rootView.getChildCount();
            TextView tv;
            for (int i = 1; i < c; i++) { // 1 because the first textview _should_ be the one from the layout
                tv = (TextView) rootView.getChildAt(i);
                if(tv.getId() != R.id.detail_text) {
                    rootView.removeViewAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I wasn't setting an id on the view I was creating, and android doesn't automatically do it in that case. I needed to add:

```
private TextView __textViewFactory(String s, RelativeLayout r, Context c, TextView above){
    TextView tv = new TextView(c);
    tv.setId(__getUniqueViewId(c));
    ...
}
...

private Integer __getUniqueViewId(Context c){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        return Utility.generateViewId(c);
    } else {
        return View.generateViewId();
    }
}
```

and in the Utility class

```
static int id = 1;

// Returns a valid id that isn't in use
public static int generateViewId(Context c){
    View rootView = ((Activity)c).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    View v = rootView.findViewById(id);
    while (v != null){
        v = rootView.findViewById(++id);
    }
    return id++;
}
```

Comment: It's not a great idea to assign your own ids to views.  That's the job of the android toolchain. It reserves the right to coordinate the assignment of all your different ids in the app to populate the R class at compile time.  If you assign your own ids, you could collide with the ids that it generates.  If you really do need your own ids, consider creating a bunch of static id resources and use those carefully in your dynamic layout.

Comment: That's silly. There are tens of thousands of code examples with assigned ids.. I've never even seen an example where you can demonstrate that the author did not provide one and yet relied on it being there at some point in the execution.

In point of fact, I actually first designed my solution assuming that the system would do _exactly_ what you suggest, and then when I found that it was **not** auto-assinging ids, I added my own, implementing a utility to avoid conflicts with other `id`s (so your concern should actually happen).

Comment: ps> In implementing my own solution, I looked at the code android uses to `generateViewId` and used roughly the same means they do to ensure that `id`s will not collide. I could imagine this could still be an issue in a threaded environment, but the base android sdk would fail in those cases too.

Comment: I'm curious - did you find any examples that come from Google doc that validate the safety of this?  How does this perform when there are many views in the hierarchy?  What if there are views that have not been attached to the hierarchy that are using a generated id, and you need to generate a bunch more before they are attached?  Be careful...

Comment: Well, the fact that android provides an non-private method `setId` should be a first clue that it is okay to do. In the [documentation of that method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29), there are several _see also_ pages. Taken as a whole, the entire collection of documentation on setId/getId/findViewById etc makes no mention of any restrictions or hazards for use. Any page that describes a view that has an xml specification will also have an "android:id" field, which is okay to populate. That is the same thing as setting it programmatically.

Comment: It's valid to use setId with existing ids generated in the app's R class. e.g. view.setId(R.id.my_view_id).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106805/discussion-between-roberto-tomas-and-doug-stevenson).

Comment: Yes, they say you can set it right there in fact:
"Supply an identifier name for this view... This must be a resource reference; **typically _you_ set this** using the @+ syntax to create a new ID resources. For example: android:id="@+id/my_id" which allows you to later retrieve the view with findViewById(R.id.my_id)."

Comment: Typically you use the @+ syntax, and you can also create your own ids in separately as a id resource.  It must be an id resource.  Making up your own numbers are not id resources.

Comment: _"and you can also create your own ids in separately as a id resource"_ I had a passing thought about that when writing my code as well. How do you programmatically assign new values to the `R.id` resource?

Comment: You don't create the programmatically.  You define them in XML and refer to them in R.id.  If it's not in R.id, it's not an id resource.  There are many strange ways your app can break or behave strangely if you don't do it like this.  If you find yourself needing an undefined number of ids, then you probably need a new layout tool, such as RecyclerView.

Comment: ooh so you mean you can either use `android:id="@+id/somekey"` or first use that somewhere and then later use "@id/somekey" to specify an object that should use the same id as previously (like when you are shifting which view is visible at a given location).

That doesn't help with programmatically generated views though. Since once can generate a view in code, it makes sense than one can specify an `id` for it (since that is part of the specification of any view). So if you don't know how that might work, try to answer this: How/when do you imagine the system will generate a conflicting id?

Comment: In XML views you can say @+id or @id.  That's fine.  In code, you can use R.id.whatever.  You can define them as resource ids like this. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id

Comment: You answered your own question, but not mine. Go back and take another look at what I just asked of you. Can you answer it? The reason that I asked is that there's nothing to worry about if the system doesn't automatically generate `id`s, and we have no reason to assume that it does at this time. It was just a concern you had. You never found a demonstration that it occurs.

Comment: To be fair, you never answered all my questions in a previous comment.  Bottom line is that you can do whatever you want, but don't be surprised if your app fails or misbehaves in strange ways in the future. What you're doing is definitely not safe in a general sense.

Comment: :) there's no reason to imagine that it will misbehave, Doug. you imagine that the system will change the id through its own internal processes, yet clearly it didn't do that when I needed it to. If making a call to a view by id doesn't force it to generate the id, then the id is unmanaged. I could write code that asks the system to change the id and then, yes, at that point the id would have changed. But that would be a change from within my own code — and I don't actually care what id is generated for the views so if the system wants to overwrite it, _fine_.

Comment: the only remaining issue might be if the system _relied_ on a view to have it's id be _unset_ if it didn't have one on creation. But if that were true, you could never set an `R.id` on a programmatically generated view either.

Comment: just to be clear, I invite you to use android studio to go to the declaration of `View.generateViewId()` —you'll see there is collision detection already in place.

Comment: But that's not what your Utility version is doing.  It's only looking at views in the *current* hierarchy, not all the views ids that could ever be used in it.  Also, generated ids have the problem of not being accessible after a configuration change where you need to reproduce the ids you generated previously for the purpose of saving and restoring state of the view.

Comment: again, that's a tempest in a teapot. until I see code that demonstrates how the system could rely on that id not being htere, I can't see an issue with it being there. the simple fact that some other item could use the same id is not a problem, its the whole reason why xml files can specifiy eiher "@+id" or "@id"

Comment: You don't need to see code.  You can simply imagine the situation.  Say you have three view ids already defined, v1=1, v2=2, v3=3.  You have v1 and v3 in the hierarchy to start. Your code wants a new id so it scans it the heirarchy and chooses the value 2.  Then you add a v2 to the hierarchy later.  Broken.  Just because an id seems available *now*, that doesn't mean it is not already occupied by something else to be used later.

Comment: There's nothing broken about that. They _intentionally designed_ ids to only have scope to a parent view hierarchy. see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)
I think the reasoning there is that they want to support flexibility in the approach of the programmer when they want to have multiple views that need to fill the same role in UX...

Comment: So how would that affect your RelativeLayout, if one view was relative to another view by id, and there were more than one view with that id?  It's a fragile situation. Again, do what you want, but if you want confidence in your solution, you'll have a hard time getting a guarantee from official documentation that nothing will go wrong.

Comment: Lastly, if you findViewById(2) on a parent that could contain both your the generated 2 and the resource v2=2, which view would you get?

Comment: frankly that's not my problem, that's a discussion for you to take up with the developers that manage Android. It is possible to do _many_ things that make your code difficult to manage. it is your responsibility to not do that. There is nothing difficult to manage in my solution here, nor is there any system-level conflict that **either of us** are aware of,  which was your first concern, and the only one that actually matters to me. It should in fact suffice for the general public, because you have to invent contorted examples to even imagine the possibility of difficulty.

Comment: This is precise the problem that I'm suggesting you're getting into.  If you depend on system level properties to be a certain way that are *not* exposed through public, documented APIs, that's a potential problem in the future.  I've seen this exactly thing trip up developers for years on a variety of platforms.  Work with the public APIs and you'll be OK, everything else is speculation going forward.

Comment: @DougStevenson let me please wipe the slate clean with you. I appreciated your attempt to answer my question, it just doesnt work by itself. The views need ids, and the system does not automatically generate them. Then I found the solution, and shared it for anyone else who might want to solve the problem, and you came and noted a concern, which was valid. I am not closing the door on that concern, if you can answer the question I posed that would lend credence to the claim. But this other idea of yours, that you can dream up some way to break the code on your own.. that's your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, above.getId());
```

I think you want this:

```
    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, above.getId());
```

Comment: actually no, that didn't fix the problem.